# SP2013 Add additional columns to a lookup field using REST

Tags: 2013, rest, lookup-column

I'm trying to create a couple of lists automatically using REST.

List A:
TextField: ID
TextField: Name

List B:
LookupField: ID (Get from list A)
LookupField: ID:Name (Additional read-only column)

Using the UI I can simply go to the settings of the lookup field ID in list B and tick the checkbox "Name" from the list "Add a column to show each of these additional fields:"
However, I struggle to do the same using REST. Does anyone know if this is possible?

I have tried to create additional lookup fields using SP.Field, but I cannot find any way to set the PrimaryFieldID.

The following produces the error: 400 Bad Request. Even if I change the type from SP.Field to SP.FieldLookup.

`$.ajax({
  url: "http://<site url>/_api/web/lists(guid'da58632f-faf0-4a78-8219-99c307747741')
    /fields('1d22ea11-1e32-424e-89ab-9fedbadb6ce1')",
  type: "POST",
  data: "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.FieldLookup' }, 'PrimaryField': <Guid of list B field ID> }",
  headers: { 
    "X-RequestDigest": <form digest value>,
    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "content-length": <length of body data>,
    "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"
  },
  success: successHandler,
  error: errorHandler
});`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out!

It worked using the /createfieldasxml endpoint.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://<site url>/_api/web
  /lists(guid'da58632f-faf0-4a78-8219-99c307747741')
  /fields('1d22ea11-1e32-424e-89ab-9fedbadb6ce1')
  /createfieldasxml",
  type: "POST",
  data: "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.XmlSchemaFieldCreationInformation' }, 'SchemaXml': "<Field Type='Lookup' Title='ID:Name' DisplayName='ID:Name' List='<GUID of list A>' ShowField='Name' FieldRef='<GUID of field ID in list B>' SourceID='<GUID of list B>' ReadOnly='TRUE' UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary='FALSE' />",
  headers: { 
    "X-RequestDigest": <form digest value>,
    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "content-length": <length of body data>,
  },
  success: successHandler,
  error: errorHandler
});
```